# HTML Japanese Encoding Issue

Tags: html, shift-jis

Facing Issue in my HTML page for Japanese OS.

After encoding to Japanese JIS my HTML form source looks like

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="info_jap" rows="3" cols="41"  Dis None >$B%&quot;%C%W%m!<%I%I%-%e%a%s%H(B</TEXTAREA></span></TD></TR><TR><TD CLASS="oddRow" valign="top"><span class="stat_contentstext">Associated Customers*</span></TD><TD CLASS="oddRow" valign="top"><span class="stat_contentstext"><TABLE  BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=1 background=""><TR><TD><span class="stat_contentstext"><SELECT MULTIPLE NAME='inpclass' Class='None' SIZE='10' ><OPTION VALUE='TEst' >TEst</SELECT></span>
```

So after the string `<%` my form breaks and cant view the rest of the form.

Suggest, what I can do for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

How do you be set at the beginning of HTML header?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-2022-jp">
```

Comment: Yes, I already has the same in my template. Didn't work as well. I tried other Japanese encoding also. not succeeded. Thanks.